# Calling a remote COM+ ServicedComponent from a C# client

Tags: .net, com+

I have a serviced component installed in a COM+ server application. I want to create an instance from a remote client. The client needs to be able to specify the server machine's name dynamically. How do I do this?

I tried using Activator:

```
            (XSLTransComponent.XSLTransformer)Activator.GetObject(
                        typeof(XSLTransComponent.XSLTransformer),
                        serverName
                        );
```

But I get this:

System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot create channel sink to connect to URL 'server'. An appropriate channel has probably not been registered.
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.Unmarshal(Type classToProxy, String url, Object data)

Do I need to register a channel? If so, how?

Another idea is to use Marshall.BindToMoniker, but how do I specify a moniker for a remote object hosted on COM+ on server x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eureka! This works:

```
string serverName = serverTextBox.Text;
Type remote = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("XSLTransComponent.XSLTransformer", serverName);
return (XSLTransComponent.XSLTransformer)Activator.CreateInstance(remote);
```

Thanks to [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxremoting/thread/6bf76216-f46d-4f04-89c5-6db450a529ac/)